# Create Conditional new variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I need to recreate the original variables of a very large data frame (900+ variables).
Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    id=c('user1','user2','user3'),
    agePanel1=c(20,25,32),
    agePanel2=c(21,NA,33),
    favColPanel1=c('blue','red','blue'),
    favColPanel2=c('red',NA,'red')
    )

     id      agePanel1 agePanel2 favColPanel1 favColPanel2
  1 user1        20        21         blue          red
  2 user2        25        NA          red           NA
  3 user3        32        33         blue          red
```

For each variable, I need to create a new variable (age and favCol below) that is NA when there is panel data and is otherwise the first panel observation. In the cases with incomplete panel data, all panel values should be set to NA. The result of this example would look like this :

```
        id    age  agePanel1 agePanel2 favCol favColPanel1 favColPanel2
    1 user1    NA      20        21      NA        blue          red           
    2 user2    25      NA        NA     red         NA            NA         
    3 user3    NA      32        33      NA        blue          red
```

I started trying something with dplyr and tidyr :

```
mutate(dat, age = ifelse(is.na(test$agePanel2),agePanel1,NA))
```

I'm struggling to find a way to do a loop or something that could automate this process.

Comment: I feel like you already have this: `dat$age <- ifelse(is.na(dat$agePanel2),dat$agePanel1,NA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most direct solution to your original question. But it seems to me that it would be desirable to get your data in long fromat. Then the operation you want to do (and most others) would be much easier.

```
# required packages
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
# get data in long format
dat_long <- dat %>% 
  gather(key, value, -id) %>% 
  separate(key, c("key", "panel"), sep = "Panel") %>%
  spread(key, value, convert = TRUE) %>% 
  arrange(id, panel) %>%
  group_by(id)
dat_long
## Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
## Groups: id
## 
##      id panel age favCol
## 1 user1     1  20   blue
## 2 user1     2  21    red
## 3 user2     1  25    red
## 4 user2     2  NA     NA
## 5 user3     1  32   blue
## 6 user3     2  33    red

# functon that does desired operation
panel_fct <- function(x){
  ifelse(is.na(x[2]), x[1], as(NA, class(x)))
}
# use mutate_each to do desired operation
dat_long %>% summarise_each(funs(panel_fct), -panel)
## Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
##
##      id age favCol
## 1 user1  NA     NA
## 2 user2  25    red
## 3 user3  NA     NA
```

Of course you can merge the final result back to your original data, but for most operations it would be desirable to use the long data instead.

```
dat_long %>% summarise_each(funs(panel_fct), -panel) %>% left_join(dat, by = "id")
## Source: local data frame [3 x 7]
## 
##      id age favCol agePanel1 agePanel2 favColPanel1 favColPanel2
## 1 user1  NA     NA        20        21         blue          red
## 2 user2  25    red        25        NA          red           NA
## 3 user3  NA     NA        32        33         blue          red
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer it was very helpful and sorry for the delay, was kinda busy these last days ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the names of the column groups that you want to manipulate, doing the manipulations for each:

```
cols <- c("age", "favCol")
for (col in cols) {
  dat[,col] <- dat[,paste0(col, "Panel1")]
  dat[!is.na(dat[,paste0(col, "Panel2")]), col] <- NA
  dat[is.na(dat[,paste0(col, "Panel2")]),paste0(col, "Panel1")] <- NA
}
dat
#      id agePanel1 agePanel2 favColPanel1 favColPanel2 age favCol
# 1 user1        20        21         blue          red  NA   <NA>
# 2 user2        NA        NA         <NA>         <NA>  25    red
# 3 user3        32        33         blue          red  NA   <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Map`

```
 dat[c('age', 'favcol')] <-Map(function(x,y) {
            indx <- rowSums(is.na(cbind(x,y)))
             x[seq_along(x)*NA^!indx]}, dat[c(2,4)], dat[c(3,5)])
 dat[rowSums(is.na(dat[2:5]))!=0,2:5] <- NA
 dat
 #    id agePanel1 agePanel2 favColPanel1 favColPanel2 age favcol
 #1 user1        20        21         blue          red  NA   <NA>
 #2 user2        NA        NA         <NA>         <NA>  25    red
 #3 user3        32        33         blue          red  NA   <NA>
```